# Reduccing number of parameters using structures in R using C

Tags: c, r

I would like to create some kind of structure to reduce the number of parameters that I have in my call from the R file.

In my R file (example.R) I have something like :

```
  ret <- .Call("example", 

        ## data
    as.double  (t(x)),
    as.integer (nr), 
    as.integer(ncol(x)),
    as.double  (y),
    as.integer (nclass),
    as.integer (cross),
        .....
)
```

And then my interface C file looks like:

```
SEXP example(SEXP x, SEXP rows, SEXP cols, 
      SEXP y, SEXP nclass, SEXP cross, SEXP sp_rows)
{
  PROTECT( x      = AS_NUMERIC( x      ) );
  PROTECT( y      = AS_NUMERIC( y      ) );

  PROTECT( cross  = AS_INTEGER( cross  ) );
  PROTECT( rows   = AS_INTEGER( rows   ) );
  PROTECT( cols   = AS_INTEGER( cols   ) );
  PROTECT( nclass = AS_INTEGER( nclass ) );
  PROTECT( sp_rows  = AS_INTEGER( sp_rows  ) );

  x_matrix = NUMERIC_POINTER(x);
  y_vector = NUMERIC_POINTER(y);

  int num_rows = INTEGER_VALUE(rows);
  .....
```

The idea is to create some kind of structure in the .R file so I can read the parameters in the .C file. Because the number of parameters needed could increase, so the human readability of the code will dramatically decrease.

Comment: A list would do what you want.  As would a data.frame.

Comment: and how do you read from a list in C ?

Comment: That's something which I haven't done, but it is possible.  Rcpp by Dirk Eddelbuettel seems popular.

Comment: There is a working example of using a list, and the picking values from it, in the RcppExamples package (which is otherwise under-used, patches welcome :-). Ok, added as answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example from the [RcppExamples](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples) package:

```
RcppExport SEXP newRcppParamsExample(SEXP params) {

    try {                                       // or use BEGIN_RCPP macro

        Rcpp::List rparam(params);              // Get parameters in params.
        std::string method   = Rcpp::as<std::string>(rparam["method"]);
        double tolerance     = Rcpp::as<double>(rparam["tolerance"]);
        int    maxIter       = Rcpp::as<int>(rparam["maxIter"]);
        Rcpp::Date startDate = Rcpp::Date(Rcpp::as<int>(rparam["startDate"])); 

        Rprintf("\nIn C++, seeing the following value\n");
        Rprintf("Method argument    : %s\n", method.c_str());
        Rprintf("Tolerance argument : %f\n", tolerance);
        Rprintf("MaxIter argument   : %d\n", maxIter);
        Rprintf("Start date argument: %04d-%02d-%02d\n",
                startDate.getYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDay());

        return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("method", method),
                                  Rcpp::Named("tolerance", tolerance),
                                  Rcpp::Named("maxIter", maxIter),
                                  Rcpp::Named("startDate", startDate),
                                  Rcpp::Named("params", params));  

    } catch( std::exception &ex ) {             // or use END_RCPP macro
        forward_exception_to_r( ex );
    } catch(...) {
        ::Rf_error( "c++ exception (unknown reason)" );
    }
    return R_NilValue; // -Wall
}
```

and here is the matching call from R:

```
RcppParamsExample <- function(params,
                              api=c("classic", "new")) {

    api <- match.arg(api)               # match to classic or new
    fun <- paste(api, "RcppParamsExample", sep="")

    ## Check that params is properly set.
    if (missing(params)) {
        cat("\nIn R, setting default argument for params\n")
        params <- list(method='BFGS',
                       tolerance=1.0e-8,
                       maxIter=1000,
                       startDate=as.Date('2006-7-15'))
    }

    ## Make the call...
    val <- .Call(fun,
                 params,
                 PACKAGE="RcppExamples")

    val
}
```

Comment: I am developing a package, if I use your library would be also needed to install your package in order to execute mine? Would it be a dependency?

Comment: Yes, Rcpp would be a dependency. Over 60 other CRAN packages depend on it --- and RcppExamples is an example for that too as it depends on Rcpp.